# Redirect - mod-rewrite

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite

I seem to have run into an interesting redirect issue.

I have one redirect that is redirecting place/ to about-us . This is working as expected.

```
#Redirecting place/ to /about-us/
RewriteRule ^place/?$ /about-us/ [NC,NS,R=301]
```

However, I have a link about-us/docs that needs to be redirected to about-us as well. This is not working. It just keeps going to about-us/docs

I've tried this

```
#Redirecting about-us/docs/ to /about-us/
RewriteRule ^about-us/docs/?$ /about-us/ [NC,NS,R=301]
```

and a few other iterations of that that just don't want to work. I am honestly stumped. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would have tagged this with apache and mod_rewrite instead of CF.  it has nothing to do with CF really.

Comment: @BradWood Sorry, I have cf on the brain. At the moment everything looks like it